# PHP Mailparse chokes on non-ascii characters

Tags: php, mime, email-parsing

I'm using Mailparse to parse and store email in a MySQL db. Emails are piped directly to a PHP script. More than 99% of emails to the system are parsed correctly. However, I noticed some emails were being truncated. The problem it seems is with unicode characters between the header and body of the message ...

```
Delivered-To: nkafq123@gmail.com
Received: by 10.152.1.193 with SMTP id 1csp311490lao;
        Mon, 20 Oct 2014 05:33:31 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <lunalono@telia.com>
Received: from vps4596.inmotionhosting.com (vps4596.inmotionhosting.com. [74.124.217.238])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id fb7si7786786pab.30.2014.10.20.05.33.30
        for <nkafq123@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Mon, 20 Oct 2014 05:33:30 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <14FBD481E1074C79A706F0C071746F3D@acerDator>
From: =?utf-8?Q?Annelen_geretschl=C3=A4ger?= <lunalono@telia.com>
To: "neokio" <nkafq123@gmail.com>
References: <CAEMnOreG=99=qx-ONib=g+3mCQnUHC2kgdu2uBdSav5WP303BA@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <CAEMnOreG=99=qx-ONib=g+3mCQnUHC2kgdu2uBdSav5WP303BA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: This message will be broken
Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 14:33:24 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0018_01CFEC72.CE424470"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
Importance: Normal
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 14.0.8117.416
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V14.0.8117.416
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 

Det här är ett flerdelat meddelande i MIME-format.

------=_NextPart_000_0018_01CFEC72.CE424470
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a test ... the above "Det här är" chunk will be cut off at "Det h", and nothing else will arrive.

------=_NextPart_000_0018_01CFEC72.CE424470
```

The above will get cropped just after the headers, and all that arrives is "Det h". Somehow, non-ascii characters (ü) are causing mailparse to choke when they're outside of the headers or multipart wrappers. This may be the 5-year old Swedish version of Microsoft Windows Live Mail the client is using, messing up headers and such, but that's no excuse, I need to be able to receive it.

I'm running PHP 5.4.30, which has `default_charset = "utf-8"` in php.ini. But I noticed that `phpinfo()` had `mailparse.def_charset = "us-ascii"` by default, even though there was no config in php.ini for it. After adding the line and setting it to "utf8", `phpinfo()` showed utf-8 correctly. However the error persists. I'm out of ideas.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this error?

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'm also writing a mailing list engine and it parses the source using the `mailparse`. Yes, it choked at that place.. will try to find solution too )

Comment: I have a question - where did you get that message? It does not follow the standards, as `quoted-printable` version of the text should be `This is a test ... the above "Det h=C3=A4r =C3=A4r" chunk will be cut off at "Det h", and nothing else will arrive.` - try it instead of your string.

Comment: Yep, the output tells the same - `Warning: mailparse_msg_extract_part() - filter conversion failed. Input message is probably incorrectly encoded`. You can extract the body directly from the file, based on the data in headers of `mailparse_msg_get_part_data` for each section, but than you have to decode it by yourself.

Comment: You're correct about the encoding, I just added that in there as a note to reference the problem. It would appear as you pointed out :)

I'm still at a loss here. It seems to me that it's the parser's job to be more tolerant of malformed MIME structure, especially somethings as simple as unicode variation. This really does only happens for a fraction of 1% of emails received ... those using buggy email clients (Microsoft Windows Live in this case). But it's still way too high to ignore. I'm happy you're seeing the error though, this tells me it's not my implementation at fault :)

Comment: The only way, probably, is to extract the content of the message part as is (it is easy) and than use `quoted_printable_decode` function if corresponding encoding is set - it does not care about problems with encoding.

Comment: Also, it is possible to catch this warning and to send message back about invalid encoding and so on )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an idea that I mentioned in the comments... This part is related to the section of the message. If, by some reason, decoding fails, the content is returned 'as is'. You can try to decode it based on `$headers['transfer-encoding'];` or leave it untouched. `$email` is a full message source with headers. `$section` is data obtained by `mailparse_msg_get_part` (manual, examples, google)

```
$headers = mailparse_msg_get_part_data($section);
$content = '';

set_error_handler(function() use(&$content, $headers, $email){
     $start   = $headers['starting-pos-body'];
     $end     = $headers['ending-pos-body'];
     $content = substr($email, $start, $end - $start);
});

ob_start();
mailparse_msg_extract_part($section, $email);
$body = ob_get_clean();

restore_error_handler();

if (!empty($content)) $body = $content;
```

Result (after some manipulations as I leave only headers that I actually need)

> ```
> ["charset"]=>
> string(5) "utf-8"
> ["content-charset"]=>
> string(5) "utf-8"
> ["content-type"]=>
> string(10) "text/plain"
> ["content"]=>
> string(108) "This is a test ... the above "Det här är" chunk will be cut off at "Det h", and nothing else will arrive. "
> ```